# Export comments in SWIG wrapper

Tags: c++, comments, swig

Suppose I have a C++ header fun.hpp:

```
//existing description of what fun1 does
void fun1(int x);
//existing description of what fun2 does
void fun2(int x);
```

I want to generate a SWIG wrapper so that the comments will appear in the target language with:

1. in a separate HTML document
2. embedded in the target generated wrapper code

Any ideas?

Comment: What language are you targeting with SWIG? Java? Python? It's sort of ugly and unsupported, I think someone is working on the more general problem though.

Comment: D although it shouldn't matter: the "hard" part should be associating C++ comments to the appropriate function/variable; given those it should be straightforward to generate comments for the target language IMHO.

Comment: I agree it shouldn't matter, but the current state of play seems to be a [GSOC branch for Doxygen->JavaDoc](http://swig.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/swig/branches/gsoc2008-cherylfoil/Doc/Manual/Doxygen.html), a [bodge with `%javamethodmodifiers`](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html#Java_javadoc_comments) and some limited [docstring support for Python](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn65).

Comment: I can associate the function-variable comment when they are inline and happens in the same line. I think comments like, `// @default(10) @format(%d)` can be used to hint code generation. But currently the swig parse tree does not have the comments.